# Instagram Basic Display API: RestSharp Invalid authorization code response

Tags: c#, .net, postman, instagram-api, restsharp

- Trying to to add an Instagram feed to my ASP.NET C# web app using [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/guides/getting-access-tokens-and-permissions) and [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/overview) documentation
- The issue is that I always get the  `Invalid authorization code` error message when trying to get the short lived token via RestSharp call to `https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token`
- In Postman the response is successful, is there something wrong with the RestSharp API call?

**RestSharp API call**

```
var client = new RestClient(_shortLivedTokenRequestString);
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);

request.AlwaysMultipartFormData = true;
request.AddParameter("client_id", _Instagram_App_Id, ParameterType.RequestBody);
request.AddParameter("client_secret", _Instagram_App_Secret, ParameterType.RequestBody);
request.AddParameter("grant_type", "authorization_code", ParameterType.RequestBody);
request.AddParameter("redirect_uri", _Instagram_App_Redirect_Uri, ParameterType.RequestBody);
request.AddParameter("code", authorizationCode, ParameterType.RequestBody);

IRestResponse<GetShortLivedTokenResponse> response = client.Execute<GetShortLivedTokenResponse>(request);
```

response: `{"error_type": "OAuthException", "code": 400, "error_message": "Invalid authorization code"}`

**response object**

[image]

**Postman request/response**

[image]

**Postman response headers**

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I recently had a similar problem that involved not removing the #_ added at the end of the code parameter like described [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/guides/getting-access-tokens-and-permissions).

I don't know if thats your case but maybe it helps

Comment: Hi Yunus, it seems that the code is being passed without the "#_" and I still get the `{"error_type": "OAuthException", "code": 400, "error_message": "Invalid authorization code"}` . not sure what the problem is, other than that do you know what are the requirements to have a correct code being sent?

Comment: @alex Did you figure out what was the problem?

Answer (score 1):

My problem was that I did not remove the `#_` as described in the [instructions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/guides/getting-access-tokens-and-permissions):

[image]